# how to prove non-pivot cloumns is the sum of preceding preceding pivot columns in RREF

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, vectors

For example,

[image]

we can see that $V_{3}=2V_{1}-3V_{2}, V_{5}=2V_{1}-2V_{2}-V_{4}$, but how can we mathematically prove the theory behind it?

Comment: http://www.math.sjsu.edu/~foster/m143m/proof_that_GE_works_color.pdf, http://math.mit.edu/~trasched/18.700.f11/gauss.pdf

Answer (score 0):

I think it follows from the definition of the RREF. Just like the vectors $$\left\{\begin{bmatrix} 1\\ 0 \end{bmatrix} , \begin{bmatrix} 0\\ 1 \end{bmatrix}\right\}$$ form a basis for $\mathbb{R}^2$, the pivot columns $$\left\{\begin{bmatrix} 1\\ 0 \\ 0\\ \cdots \\ 0\end{bmatrix} , \begin{bmatrix} 0\\ 1 \\ 0 \\ \cdots \\ 0\end{bmatrix}\right\}$$ form a basis for vectors of the form $$\begin{bmatrix} a\\ b \\ 0\\ \cdots \\ 0\end{bmatrix}$$ and in RREF, columns with $n$ leading nonzero entries are guaranteed to be "behind" the first $n$ pivot columns.